# Uncaught ReferenceError: getProduct is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am building an E-commerce website.

My problem is that when a customer clicks on a product, how do I save all the data of that product (id, name, price) in a javascript object and then send the array of select product objects to a PHP file using Ajax?

this is my current implementation:

```
  <?php 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($product))
{
    $id=$row['id'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    $price=$row['price'];
?>
<div class="product" onclick="getProduct(this)">
    <p data-pid="<?php echo $id ?>" ><?php echo $id ?></p>
    <p data-pname="<?php echo $name ?>"><?php echo $name ?></p>
    <div class="product-footer">
        <p data-pprice="<?php echo $price ?>"><?php echo $price ?></p>
        <button>Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

JS Code:

```
var products = new Array();
var product= new Object();
function getProduct(obj) {
     product.id = $(obj+' [data-pid]').data('pid');
     product.name= $(obj+' [data-pname]').data('pname');
     product.price= $(obj+' [data-pprice]').data('price');
     products.push(product);
     console.log(products);
}
```

this implementation is not working I get this javsscript error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getProduct is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: do you have to build form scratch when there are so many open-source e-commerce scripts available.

Comment: i don't know about these scripts. please provide a link if you have one.

Comment: do you mean like Wordpress WooCommerce?

Comment: Please update your title with your `error` you're getting. This question is so unclear

Comment: there are hundreds,that i would say are better than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> //Jquery Plugin

     <?php 
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($product)){echo '
        <div class="product" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" data-name="'.$row['name'].'" data-price="'.$row['price'].'">
            <p>'.$row['id'].'</p>
            <p>'.$row['name'].'</p>
            <div class="product-footer"><p>'.$row['price'].'</p><button>Add To Cart</button></div>
        </div>';
        }
    ?>
    <script>
    $('.product').click(function(e) {
        product = {'id':$(this).data('id'),'name':$(this).data('name'),'price':$(this).data('price')};
        console.log(product);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: this solution is working but when i try to push the product object in an array, every time the user clicks on the product it replaces all the previously stored objects with the same object that user has selected. For example if the user has selected a mobile phone and then selects a tablet, the function pushes 2 tablets objects in the array

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I had to change the product object to an empty object after pushing it in the array, now it is working. Thanks a lot